# Add / Remove class based on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a lot sections on my page and all of them is full height and full width. Each section includes an image.

So, When visitor scroll up or scroll down to current section, that image on the section will show up. If user skips the another section, that image on previous section is going to hide.

There is live example. Like this; https://cliquestudios.com

Lets say these are my codes. When user on active section, it should add "active" class to "article" tag. When user left that section, "active" class should be removed and "active" class should be added to user's current section.

```css
.section .image {
   opacity: 0;
}

.section .active .image {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
    <section class="all-sections-wrap">

    <article class="section">

    <div class="image">
    <img src="blabla.png">
    </div>

    </article>

    <article class="section">

    <div class="image">
    <img src="blabla.png">
    </div>

    </article>

    <article class="section">

    <div class="image">
    <img src="blabla.png">
    </div>

    </article>

    <section>
```

I was investigated a lot topic in stackoverflow but unfortunately i could not find well enough script.These had a lot of issue about detecting offset and page height.

I would be grateful if i could get any help.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried something like ScrollMagic? http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/class_toggles.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`.scroll()` callback](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) on the `window` element to know when the page is scrolled. Then, you can get from how many pixels the page is scrolled with [`$(window).scrollTop()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/). Finally, compare it to the offset of the element you want to add the class to with [`$("#element").offset().top`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/)

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#element").offset().top + $("#element").height() || $(window).scrollTop() < $("#element").offset().top)
        $('#element').removeClass('active');
    else
        $('#element').addClass('active');
});
```

If you have many sections, to avoid replicating the above code, use [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/). However be careful, testing every section everytime `scroll()` is called may have a big performance impact.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    $('.section').each(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() || $(window).scrollTop() < $(this).offset().top)
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        else
            $(this).addClass('active');
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried your code. It works partly but there is an issue. This works only on first section. When skipped the first section and scroll down to second section or another section, all images are hiding too in other sections. When i come back to first section; all images are showing again. That's not my wish. Could you fix this?

Comment: I think you used the wrong selectors. Don't use class selectors (`.section` for example) but ids instead. (`#element` for example)

Comment: Yeah i used to use class selectors. I have defined different id for every section. In this way, Its okay. But now, I'm using your code repeatedly with different id. I mean, for example; i have 20 sections in my page. So i have to define 20 different id and must clone the javascript code for these defined ids. How can we do this more dynamic? I mean code should based on class selectors. I think, to do this, need for loop.

Comment: Yes I think loops will do the trick. You can also try with [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/). However be careful, testing every section everytime `scroll` is called may have a big performance impact.

Comment: Well i haven't so experienced with JS. Could you help me about the update code?

Comment: That is what i want. Thank you so much!